# Refill a ListView in android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

How to refill a ListView in android

```
    listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    listview.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Names));

    final String[] TempArray = new String[Names.length];

    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
    {

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method 
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

That was my sample code. I want to refill the listview on  public void **onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int int count)** function.on onTextChanged function, i want to fill the listview with a new string array.  how can i do this???

Comment: what do you mean by refill? is it filtering the list item?

Comment: on onTextChanged function, i want to fill the listview with a new string array

Comment: that's not so complicated, you have a problem, you must have tried something already, and despite your best efforts you can't get it to work. So, what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are filling the adapter with "Names" values, What you can do is onTextChanged clear the old data from "Names" and add the new data and set the Adapter.

Comment: on onTextChanged function, i want to fill the listview with a new string array

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get your adapter into a variable:

```
ArrayAdapter mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Names);
listview.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Then, when you need to refill you list (e.g. when "Names" changed) just call

```
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

what you need is just put `notifyDataSetChanged();` method in your `onTextChanged` method.

**Like :**

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
{
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method 
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
});
```

Hope this help.. enjoy..

Answer (score 0):

You can't call notifyDataSetChanged() inside any of TextWatcher methods call which will throws [RecyclerView notifyDatasetChange() illegalstateexception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27070220/recycleview-notifydatasetchanged-illegalstateexception)

What I did to achieve auto-add new row inside RecyclerView list is by implementing OnFocusChangeListener interface which will auto-add once editText gain user focused and also able to avoid above error.

```
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus)
                // ADD NEW ITEM INTO LIST
                notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the code bellow to recreate your list adapter:

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
{

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method 
        Names = new ArrayList<~>();
        Names.add('your object');
        listview.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                             android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, Names));
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
```

and if you just want to add new data to your 'Names' arrayList you could use code bellow:

```
 editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
{

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
            int count)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method 
        Names.add('your object');
        listview.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
            int after)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
```