# Recycler View doesnt update the contains on notifyDataSetChanged

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am using Recycler view to display a list of elements. Each row has a button on it when we click it status changes and its background color. I am calling notifyDataSetChanged() once the status is updated but recyclerView is not getting refreshed.

```
else if (allGoals.getStatus() == WorkoutCashConstants.GOALS_ACHIEVE) {
                        boolean networkStatus = checkNetworkStatus();
                        if (networkStatus) {
                            dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                            if (DATE_ACCESS == null) {
                                currentTimeStamp = dateFormat.format(new Date());
                            } else {
                                currentTimeStamp = DATE_ACCESS;
                            }
                            progDialog = ProgressDialog.show(CompanyGoals_AllGoals_Fragment.this.getActivity(), "", "Goal Progress Recorded");
                            progDialog.setCancelable(true);
                            AchieveGoals achieveGoals = new AchieveGoals(Integer.parseInt(allGoals.getGoalID()), currentTimeStamp);
                            Call<AchieveGoals> achieveGoalsCall = apiModule.achieveGoal(achieveGoals);
                            achieveGoalsCall.enqueue(new Callback<AchieveGoals>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(Response<AchieveGoals> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
                                    progDialog.dismiss();
                                    if (response.isSuccess()) {
                                        progDialog.dismiss();
                                        goalsAchieved = response.body();
                                        if (goalsAchieved.getAppStatusCode() == WorkoutCashConstants.SUCCESS_API) {
                                            realm = Realm.getInstance(getContext());
                                            realm.beginTransaction();
                                            AllGoalsDB goalsDB = realm.where(AllGoalsDB.class)
                                                    .equalTo("goalID", allGoals.getGoalID()).findFirst();

                                            CompeletedDatesDB compeletedDatesDB = realm.createObject(CompeletedDatesDB.class);
                                            compeletedDatesDB.setCompletedDate(currentTimeStamp);
                                            goalsDB.getCompeletedDatesDBs().add(compeletedDatesDB);
                                            realm.commitTransaction();


                                            UserInfoDB userInfoDB = realm.where(UserInfoDB.class)
                                                    .equalTo(WorkoutCashConstants.
                                                            COLUMN_USER_ID, userId)
                                                    .findFirst();

                                            if (userInfoDB != null) {
                                                realm.beginTransaction();
                                                userInfoDB.setSweatPoints(goalsAchieved.getData().getSweatPoints());
                                                realm.commitTransaction();
                                            }




                                            realm.close();



                                            notifyDataSetChanged();

                                        }
                                    }
```

Comment: Please Check this for better understanding the Update the RecycleView Android http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27070220/recycleview-notifydatasetchanged-illegalstateexception

Comment: @RajanBhavsar How is viewing a checkbox example related to my issue over here. Should i call notifyDataSetChanged() on handler??

Comment: Nop For that You should have to make Listener in ViewHolder Class and then need to handle that. same as CheckBox handled in above link

Comment: @RajanBhavsar A still but unclear could you help me with say pseudoCode

Comment: I think you should place a method inside recyclerview adapter and update the data from there. and at the end of this method, put the statement this.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: @RajanBhavsar I tried moving code in View Holder. still NotifyDataSetChanged() is not working.

Comment: @ishworkafley hows is it any different from now what I am doing??

Comment: Adapter is responsible for providing data and appearance to each of the items of recyclerview.When you update recyclerview from a seperate method inside an adapter, the update gets reflected in view right?

Comment: @ishworkafley yep. So i am using the click listener in viewHolder  and when I get desired result I call notifyDataSetChanged(). what am I missing here??

Comment: Viewholder your talking about is an inner class of parent adapter class I presume.And the parent class is not so very aware of classes existing inside it . so Its not so very good idea updating adapter from inner class.Beside,How bout defining a seperate method in adapter, provide data to this method and at the end  apply notifyDataSetChanged. once the adapter gets notified about the updated data, you can use the same data from viewholder and the whole change gets reflected in your recycler view.

Comment: @ishworkafley the If clause which I am using above it to pursue the same function I am using notifyDataSetChanged and its working fine whereas when I use here in this respect scenario its failing to update the recyclerView

Answer (score 0):

notifyDataSetChanged() checkes getItemCount() and if the item count in the list associated with the adapter is changed the notifyDataSetChanged() takes effect. In your case you might use a toggleSelection function inside your adapter. I'm attaching one of my example adapter so that, you can have an idea about how we can achieve this behaviour.

```
public class ToggleSelectionListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

        private Cursor mCursor;
        private SparseBooleanArray selectedItems;

        public ToggleSelectionListAdapter(Cursor cursor) {
            mCursor = cursor;
            selectedItems = new SparseBooleanArray();
        }

        public void toggleSelection(int pos) {
            if (selectedItems.get(pos, false)) {
                selectedItems.delete(pos);
            } else {
                selectedItems.put(pos, true);
            }
            notifyItemChanged(pos);
        }

        public int getSelectedItemCount() {
            return selectedItems.size();
        }

        public void clearSelections() {
            selectedItems.clear();
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
                super(itemView);

                // Initialize your items of each row here
            }

            public void bindView(int pos) {
                try {
                    if (mCursor.isClosed())
                        return;

                    mCursor.moveToPosition(pos);

                    // Maintain a checked item list so that you can have a track if the item is clicked or not
                    if (checkedItems.contains(number) itemView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_selected);
                    else itemView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_normal);

                    itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                                    if (checkedItems.contains(number)) {
                                        checkedItems.remove(number);
                                    } else {
                                        checkedItems.add(number);
                                    }

                                // Get the index of which item should toggle the background
                                int idx = mRecyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(v);
                                toggleSelection(idx);
                            }
                        }
                    });
            }
        }


        @Override
        public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

            View v;

            v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_row, parent, false);

            ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);

            return vh;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

            if (holder instanceof ViewHolder) {
                ViewHolder vh = (ViewHolder) holder;

                vh.bindView(position);

            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {

            if (mCursor == null) {
                return 0;
            }

            int n = mCursor.getCount();
            return n;
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            return super.getItemViewType(position);
        }

        synchronized public void swapCursor(Cursor cursor) {
            mCursor = cursor;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

Comment: toggle selection won't work for me because I am using realm database in my recycler view while deleting it and putting it back might give Object invalid index error which I have faced earlier. I am just confused why my notifyDataSetChanged() is not working when I am doing every correct I guess

Comment: Try setAdapter while you're reinitializing your database.

Comment: Didn't quite got you??

Comment: Try reinitializing the adapter with the new dataset  and then call recylerview.setAdapter() again. This is not a very good approach, but might work in your case.

Comment: Ohh ya that approach works but its kinda very bad say if you are changing the 6th item it refreshes the list and recycler view is back at top. User experience gets spoiled

Comment: You can save the scrolled position and can return to the last scrolled position again. `mLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(savedPostion, 0)`