# Cannot call this method while RecyclerView is computing a layout or scrolling

Tags: android, android-activity, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I already tried looking at this answer which answers a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31069171/6313011

I am getting this error:

"Cannot call this method while RecyclerView is computing a layout or scrolling"

In my adapter class I have a private boolean `mOnBind` init to false.

Then I have

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {
        mOnBind = true;
        holder.bindRow(myList.get(position), position);
        mOnBind = false;
    }
```

And then in my `RecyclerViewHolder` method I have:

```
myEditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean focus) {
                    if (!mOnBind && !focus) {
                        notifyDataSetChanged(); //causes error!
                    }
                }
            });
```

I thought using the `mOnBind` approach would fix the error but apparently not. How do I fix?