# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid view holder adapter positionViewHolder{5280f810 position=0 id=-1, oldPos=0,

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

There is something wrong with the below methods, but I do not know how to fix it:

```
mDataSet.remove(position - 1);
notifyItemRemoved(position);
notifyItemRangeChanged(0, getItemCount());
```

Entire class:

```
public class DemoAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener {

    private static final int TYPE_HEADER = 0;
    private static final int TYPE_NORMAL = 1;
    private Context mContext;
    private List<String> mDataSet;

    private MyViewHolder normalHolder;
    private HeaderHolder headerHolder;

    public DemoAdapter(List<String> mDataSet, Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mDataSet = mDataSet;
    }

    public void setData(List<String> mDataset) {
        this.mDataSet = mDataset;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void Remove(int position) {
        mDataSet.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }

    public void Add(String text, int position) {
        mDataSet.add(position, text);
        notifyItemInserted(position);
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Context context = parent.getContext();
        if (viewType == TYPE_HEADER) {
            //inflate header layout
            View headerview = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_main_recyclerview_headerview, parent, false);
            headerHolder = new HeaderHolder(headerview, mContext);
            return headerHolder;

        } else if (viewType == TYPE_NORMAL) {
            View normalView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.activity_main_recyclerview_itemview, parent, false);
            normalHolder = new MyViewHolder(normalView, mContext);
            return normalHolder;
        }

        // set the view's size, margins, paddings and layout parameters
        //return viewHolder;
        throw new RuntimeException("there is no type that matches the type " + viewType + " + make sure your using types correctly");
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        LogUtils.I("COCO", " bind position:" +  position );

        if (holder instanceof HeaderHolder) {
            //test headerview's click listener happens correctly
            headerHolder = (HeaderHolder) holder;

            headerHolder.image.setOnClickListener(this);

        } else if (holder instanceof MyViewHolder) {
            //to avoid outofindexexception, as header size = 1
            String data = mDataSet.get(position - 1);
            normalHolder = (MyViewHolder) holder;

            normalHolder.mTextview.setOnClickListener(this);
            normalHolder.ll_itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            normalHolder.ll_itemView.setOnLongClickListener(this);
            normalHolder.mTextview.setOnLongClickListener(this);

            normalHolder.mTextview.setTag(position);
            normalHolder.ll_itemView.setTag(position);

            normalHolder.mTextview.setText(data);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (null != mDataset && mDataset.size() > 0)
            //return mDataSet.size();
            //+1 is header's size
            return mDataSet.size() + 1;

        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (position == 0)
            return TYPE_HEADER;

        return TYPE_NORMAL;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View view) {

        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.activity_main_recyclerview_itemview:
                //click to remove itemview, as existing headerview so position -1
                int position = (int) view.getTag();
                mDataSet.remove(position - 1);
                notifyItemRemoved(position);
                notifyItemRangeChanged(0, getItemCount());

                LogUtils.I("COCO", "data position:" +  view.getTag() );
                LogUtils.I("COCO", " item position:" +  position );
                break;

            case R.id.activity_main_recyclerview_itemview_textview:
                LogUtils.I("COCO", "long click content:" + normalHolder.mTextview.getText());
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: i wanna test itemview's delete event when having a headerview. everything goes well, but when i delete the last normal itemview, it run to the above exception, i have try it, but donot know how to fix it, and if i use notifyDataSetChange() instead of notifyItemRemove() method, it did not exist this exception, but the headerview was removed as well, when i deleted the last normal itemview. Hope someone could help me out, thanks!

Comment: You should edit tour question instead of posting a comment. Please do your best to use correct punctuation and capitalization. We are aware that not everyone speaks and writes English as their primary language and can be very forgiving about grammar and such. You should still do all that you can to make it easier for us to understand your question. Thank you.

Comment: I have fixed it. the getItemCount() method needs to return 1, not 0