# NotifyItemRemoved not working properly using firebaserecycleradapter?

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

I'm using `firebase-ui` to retrieve from firebase and I want to remove from displaying all the `status` that are equal to `unlive` I don't want to delete it from `firebase database` but only removed it from displaying on the `recyclerview` tried also doing the solution [Cannot call this method while RecyclerView is computing a layout or scrolling when try remove item from recyclerview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43221847/cannot-call-this-method-while-recyclerview-is-computing-a-layout-or-scrolling-wh) here still encountering the error. Please help I'm stuck here for days. Can't find any solution. Thanks

```
mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Hotels_Model, Adapter_HotelsHolder>(mOptions) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(Adapter_HotelsHolder holder,int position, Hotels_Model model) {

                String status = model.getStatus();
                if (status.equals("unlive")) {
                    mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(holder.getAdapterPosition());
                    mAdapter.notifyItemRangeChanged(holder.getAdapterPosition(), getItemCount());
                }

        }
```

This is my error if I scroll to the `position` where the status is `unlive`

```
Cannot call this method while RecyclerView is computing a layout or scrolling android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
```

Answer (score 0):

So you can do it easily in that way:

```
mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Hotels_Model, Adapter_HotelsHolder>(mOptions) {
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(Adapter_HotelsHolder holder,int position, Hotels_Model model) {

                String status = model.getStatus();
                if (status.equals("unlive")) {
                  holder.yourRowView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

        }
```

You don't need to remove your items from recyclerview.