# ViewPager2 with ListAdapter (from android) shows java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-viewpager, android-livedata

When I am using androidx ListAdapter with ViewPager2 and try to update the specific list item from fragment with *adapter.notifyItemChanged*, I have crash that shows *java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call this method while RecyclerView is computing a layout or scrolling*.

Previously I was using recyclerView and could resolve the crash by the condition with *if(recyclerView.isComputingLayout())* before *adapter.notifyItemChanged*. Unfortunately ViewPager does not have method that returns computing information. Also, checking the stateScroll gives me nothing. Maybe someone had this problem before? Here's code:

```
viewModel.invoicePositionList.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
        if (viewModel.currentInvoicePositionPosition >= 0) {
            adapter.notifyItemChanged(viewModel.currentInvoicePositionPosition)
            viewModel.currentInvoicePositionPosition = -1
        } else {
            adapter.submitList(it)
        }
    })
```

Comment: try answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43221847/cannot-call-this-method-while-recyclerview-is-computing-a-layout-or-scrolling-wh)

Comment: Hey, I tried the post solution previously. It works at first, however then after a new item is added to list the recycler/viewPager is staggering, working slowly and frames are visible :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not expected to call `notifyItemChanged` when using `ListAdapter`. All you need is to create a new list without the removed item and call `submitList`.