# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call this method while RecyclerView is computing a layout or scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to remove an item from listview which is not starting a specific text "Dev". But the application is crashing when I remove an item and refresh the recycler list via notifydatasetChanged(). This question has been already asked and I have seen all the solutions but I can't find a proper solution to this.

**EvelistAdapter.java**

```
     public class EvelistAdater extends RecyclerView.Adapter<EvelistAdater.ViewHolder> {
    Context cxt;
    ArrayList<Dbbean> adapterlist;
    int row_index;
    public EvelistAdater(Context cxt, ArrayList<Dbbean> list) {
        adapterlist=list;
        this.cxt=cxt;
        Log.d("LIst count",""+adapterlist.size());
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.scanlistadp, viewGroup, false);
        return  new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        if(adapterlist.get(position).blename.startsWith("Dev")) {
            holder.tv_country.setText(adapterlist.get(position).blename);

        }else{
            removeAt(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return adapterlist.size();
    }
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView tv_country;
        RelativeLayout layout;
        ImageView setting;
        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            tv_country = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tshirtname);
            setting = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.setting);
            layout = (RelativeLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.layout);
        }
    }
    public void removeAt(int position) {
        adapterlist.remove(position);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

**LOGCAT**

```
E/UncaughtException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call this method while RecyclerView is computing a layout or scrolling
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.assertNotInLayoutOrScroll(RecyclerView.java:2586)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$RecyclerViewDataObserver.onItemRangeChanged(RecyclerView.java:4951)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$AdapterDataObservable.notifyItemRangeChanged(RecyclerView.java:11371)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$AdapterDataObservable.notifyItemRangeChanged(RecyclerView.java:11362)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.notifyItemChanged(RecyclerView.java:6650)
                                                                        at com.scanner.com.eve.EvelistAdater.removeAt(EvelistAdater.java:94)
                                                                        at com.scanner.com.eve.EvelistAdater.onBindViewHolder(EvelistAdater.java:44)
                                                                        at com.scanner.com.eve.EvelistAdater.onBindViewHolder(EvelistAdater.java:19)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6354)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6387)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5343)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5606)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5448)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5444)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2224)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1551)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1511)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:595)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3600)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3329)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3867)
                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16655)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5438)
                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16655)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5438)
                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16655)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5438)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.onLayout(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:636)
                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16655)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5438)
                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16655)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5438)
                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1743)
                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1586)
                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1495)
                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16655)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5438)
                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:336)
                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:273)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2895)
                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16655)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5438)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2171)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1931)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
                                                                        at android.view.ViewR
```

Comment: At first use different name `this.list=list;` and share logcat

Comment: You have to remove `notifyDataSetChanged()` from `onBindViewHolder()`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya question updated with logcat

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27070220/android-recyclerview-notifydatasetchanged-illegalstateexception

Comment: @Sekhar agree with #Heisen-Berg's comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter the data in `list` before passing to `Adapter`

```
 ArrayList<Dbbean> list = yourlist;
```

Create a filtered `list`

```
  ArrayList<Dbbean> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
  for(Dbbean dbean : list){
    if(dbean.blename.startsWith("Dev")
     filteredList.add(dbean);
  }
```

Pass filtered list to Adapter

```
EvelistAdapter adapter = new EvelistAdaptr(this,filteredList);
yourRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Thanks, Rajan it is working but I am getting the same name twice how to remove the same name in one list?

Comment: Just check for duplicate name entry .

Answer (score 1):

Do not call `removeItem` inside `onBindViewHolder` directly. If you want to remove item then just do it before setting adapter.

Provide the filtered `ArrayList<Dbbean> list` to adpater in first place .Later you can remove item from adapter on any specified action.
 Do not use `notifyDataSetChanged()` until you are not sure which dataset is changed. Use :
`notifyItemRemoved()` for a particular item removed for position .

Answer (score 0):

this is causing the problem you are just forcefully making changes to the onBindViewHolder which is drawing something right now again to redraw.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    if(adapterlist.get(position).blename.startsWith("Dev")) {
        holder.tv_country.setText(adapterlist.get(position).blename);

    }else{
        removeAt(position);
    }
}

public void removeAt(int position) {
    adapterlist.remove(position);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

suggestion better check this condition and remove the items when you are about to notify the adapter from fragment or activity.

Comment: Thank you Vikas you are right and now I am using Rajan's solution and its working